# Leer array en Json y mostrarlo en un Grid

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Tengo mi código de JSON así.

```
function obtener_Personas() {

var id_Persona = 1;
var Trabajo = "";
var id_Usuario = 1;


if (id_Persona != 0) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersonas.aspx/ListarPersonas",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"'+id_Persona+'",Trabajo:"'+Trabajo+'",ROl:"'+id_Usuario+'"}',

        success: function(data) {
            alert("Entro correcto Ok");
            Datasourcefuncion(data.d);               
        },

        error: function(error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
            console.log(error.responseText);
            jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(Error.responseText);
            alert(error.respose.Text);
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
else 
    alert("error en id_Persona");
    return false;


}
```

El cual me retorna un resultado como este:

```
[

{"Nombre":"Federico", "Apellido":"Navarrete", "Edad":39},

{"Nombre":"Rodrigo", "Apellido":"Navarrete", "Edad":15},

{"Nombre":"Victor", "Apellido":"López", "Edad": 60}

]
```

Como puedo recorrer ese array para guardar sus elementos y mostrarlo en mi control (jqxGrid).

Comment: que has intentado? investiga [esta librería](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: Hola Juan mira he intentado este pedazo de codigo el cual no me muestra mis datos. Ya que yo quiero mostrar mis datos sin declararlos.

function Datasourcefuncion(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        dataFieldsArray=data[i];
                    
                    }
                        var source =
            {
                datatype: "json",
                datafields: dataFieldsArray,
                localdata: data
            };
                
            }

Answer (score 0):

No se recorre nada debes poder asignar el "source"

[data binding in grid via $.ajax](https://www.jqwidgets.com/community/topic/data-binding-in-grid-via-ajax/)

Tienes que poder asignar el `source` con los datos que provienen de la llamada `$.ajax`

en el `success` del `$.ajax` podrias definir los datos del `jqxgrid` asignando el `source`

```
success: function (data) {
        // initailize grid
        var gridData = data;
        var gridSource =
        {
            localdata: gridData,
            datatype: 'json'
        };
        var gridDataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(gridSource);
        $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
        {
            width: 670,
            source: gridDataAdapter,
            editable: true,
            pageable: true,
            autoheight: true,
            selectionmode: 'singlecell',
            columns: [
              { text: 'Name', datafield: 'name', width: 250 },
              { text: 'Beverage Type', datafield: 'type', width: 250 },
              { text: 'Calories', datafield: 'calories', width: 180 },
              { text: 'Total Fat', datafield: 'totalfat', width: 120 },
              { text: 'Protein', datafield: 'protein', minwidth: 120 }
          ]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo es si ajax, y funciona:

```
public class Dato
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string Edad { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Dato> datos { get; set; }
    }
```

En tu metodo obtener_Personas() llamas asi:

```
var resultjson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
foreach (var item in resultjson.datos)
                {
                    int filaadd = datagrid.Rows.Add();
                    datagrid.Rows[filaadd].Cells["nombre"].Value = item.Nombre;
                    datagrid.Rows[filaadd].Cells["apellido"].Value = item.Apellido;
                    datagrid.Rows[filaadd].Cells["edad"].Value = item.Edad;


                }
```

prueba de esta manera, si tienes dudas me comentas.